# PHP memory usage - is 1.5MB a lot?

Tags: php, memory, ram

I'm running a site on a VPS and is reaching 93% memory usage regularly. I used the memory_get_usage() function in PHP on one of the larger pages and it said it was using over 1,500,000 in memory. Is that a lot? Is there a common benchmark for a healthy site?

My site isn't even all that complex, though it's hand-coded not using any framework.

Of concern is that fact that I traced the big jump in memory usage to the line of code where it includes one file (125kb) that contains all my PHP functions (yes I should probably separate the functions into separate libraries and include them as required).

Memory usage for that page jumps from 250k to 1.4MB right after including that file. Is this normal? None of those functions are actually being called yet, it's just a function library.

Comment: You do know that even consumer RAM is on the order of gigabytes now, right? 1.5MB / 1GB is not much.

Comment: You're using approximately 1.4MB of RAM - this shouldn't make a difference on your VPS (even if, say, you only had 256MB allotted). That said, you can try to use the `unset` method to free some memory internally if you are concerned.

Comment: php when running uses between 5 and 10 megabytes just for the language.  The machine running php typically has 2000 to 4000 megabytes.  1.5 megabytes is not a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.5mb is nothing to worry about for a PHP program.

20mb would be not worry me either.

50mb would be a bit more worrying, depending on what the program is doing.

But of course, it does depend very much on the individual program.

In your case, adding a bunch of functions to the script would definitely take up a chunk of memory of the kind of order you've seen. Nothing out of the ordinary there.

But 1.5meg isn't a lot. How much RAM does your VPS have? How many concurrent PHP scripts are running to blow out your entire RAM allocation?

You may have a problem with the speed of your script -- a PHP script should run in a minimal space of time, so that 1.5mb should not be in use for long. But if you've got a script that takes too much time, it could cause more users to be running the script at the same time. In addition, if it's slow, those users could try hitting refresh a few times, which will definitely blow out your memory, as the single user will be running multiple copies of the script at once. So look for ways to improve the performance of your code; this could help you.

Another question: Are your pages static? Could it be cached? ie if your PHP page generates the same HTML output each time it's loaded, you could save yourself a lot of RAM (and drastically improve performance) by caching the output so that the PHP code doesn't need to be run every single time the page is requested. A caching server like Varnish will help with this.

I hope that helps answer the question and give you a few more directions for thought.

Comment: My site gets 75,000 unique visitors per month. The VPS has 768MB RAM, not a full GB. Whenever I do a health check, it's around 92-95% memory usage, which worries me. I've had the server go down because the memory got max'd.

My site is also considered slow by Alexa, though I think that's more the HTTP side, not PHP.

This is the memory used on a typical page load, not a script that runs for any length of time.

The pages aren't static, as they pull up-to-date product rating averages from the database.

Comment: For the included function library, maybe I'll cut it into different libraries and include them as necessary.

 Is the amount of memory used simply proportional to the lines of code, in essence, or is the type of function (what it does or contains, maybe arrays, etc) also affect it significantly?

Comment: re your first comment: even if the pages aren't totally static, if you're loading the same page more than a few times, you will benefit a lot from a cache system like Varnish.

Comment: re your second comment: splitting libraries down into smaller chunks is a good idea. Also, if you've got your code written as classes, you can use PHP's autoloading mechanism which allows you to include individual classes automatically when the program needs them, without having to manually include any of them; you just call the class, and it includes itself automatically.